# Count how many times a string of length N appears in a cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a cell that contains order numbers, separated by a comma. (i.e. `1689519145, 2944241, 1689611938`).

I'm trying to get a formula to count how many times the 7 digit order number appears in the cell, if present.

My research lead me to this formula, which counts how many times sometime appears between delimiters, but I can't figure out how to parse ONLY 7 digit order numbers: `=LEN(P9)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(P9,",",""))+1`

Comment: The number of times a specific 7-digit Order Number appears within the cell, or a total for all 7-digit Order Numbers appearing within the cell?

Answer (score 1):

If you are counting all seven digit numbers you can use something like this

```
{=SUM(IF((1*TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",REPT(" ",99)),(ROW(OFFSET($A$1,,,LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",""))+1))-1)*99+((ROW(OFFSET($A$1,,,LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",""))+1)))=1),99)))>999999,IF((1*TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",REPT(" ",99)),(ROW(OFFSET($A$1,,,LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",""))+1))-1)*99+((ROW(OFFSET($A$1,,,LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",""))+1)))=1),99)))<10000000,1)))}
```

which counts all numbers between 999,999 and 10,000,000.

Alternatively if you want to count how many times a specific number appears, you can adapt the formula to something like this

```
=SUM(IF((1*TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A3,",",REPT(" ",99)),(ROW(OFFSET($A$1,,,LEN(A3)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A3,",",""))+1))-1)*99+((ROW(OFFSET($A$1,,,LEN(A3)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A3,",",""))+1)))=1),99)))=2944241,1))
```

where you could also replace the specific 7 digit numbers as a (2944241 in this case) with a reference.

Keys to make the formula work:

1. Make sure the instances of `ROW(OFFSET($A$1` stay `ROW(OFFSET($A$1` or at least on the first row
2. Enter the formula as an array (the whole ctl+shift+enter)

How the formula works:

1. `SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",REPT(" ",99)` goes through and splits up each number by 99 spaces
2. `LEN(A3)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A3,",",""))` counts how many items there are
3. `ROW(OFFSET($A$1,,` creates an array with as many items
4. the first array is multiplied by 99
5. one is added to the first element of the array
6. `MID` then cuts up the array as many times as the elements, cutting a different element each time
7. `TRIM` removes the extra spaces
8. the array is multiplied by one to turn them from strings to numbers
9. the `SUM` counts how many of the array fit the criteria of the `IF`

Credit goes to [Ron Rosenfeld](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2872922/ron-rosenfeld) for most of the [heavy lifting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25316094/split-a-string-cell-in-excel-without-vba-e-g-for-array-formula)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this using Len()/Substitute(), then

`=(LEN(A2)+2-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(" "&A2&",","0","|"),"1","|"),"2","|"),"3","|"),"4","|"),"5","|"),"6","|"),"7","|"),"8","|"),"9","|")," |||||||,","")))/LEN(" |||||||,")`

Instead of | you can place any other symbol that is not in the string.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me as if you desire the number of times an exact, particular seven digit number appears in the target cell rather than how many numbers of whatever lengths and digits appear in the cell. (That might also be dscribed as how many "elements" are in the target cell, like one would say in "elements of an array.")

And from the formula your research produces, I believe you are seeing answers for both and not realizing they differ so the proper formulas must also differ and then using the wrong one for your need here.

First, how many elements are there? Each is separated by a comma, so there are however many commas there are PLUS one (because the last element has no comma following it so you have to add that one more). So if you SUBSTITUTE() "nothing at all" ( "" in the Excel world) for each comma, the length of the target string will be shorter by how many commas there are in the original string. Your formula does that. But you do the "+1" part incorrectly in it. Given the otherwise unneeded () pair around the SUBSTITUTE() function, I think you knew to put the "+1" inside them but just typed it wrong here. If you leave it outside, you have to subtract it ("-1"). Subtract the shorter length AND the 1 from the original length and you have how many elements.

But... if you really do need to know how many times an exact seven digit string appears, precisely that and nothing more, then you need to use the same concept but slightly differently. Begin by using SUBSTITUTE() to exchange a "nothing" for the string you want to count. Subtract that from the original length. Finally, divide that difference by the length of the string you wanted to know about:  seven digits here, maybe some other length some other use some other time and place. So:

```
= ( LEN(P9) - SUBSTITUTE(P9,"1234567","") ) / 7
```

Of course, if you have the string in some other cell, you can put it in the formula instead of my "1234567" and make your formula more useful!

On the off chance you want to know how many EXACTLY seven digits long, no more, no less long, numbers are in P9, you can use array functions to look at each element for length and count those that are seven digits only. Kind of complicated and if you need to add looking for letters and ignoring those elements, it is more so. And... well you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

**Follow these steps to count how many times the 7 digit order number appears in the cell.**

*I'm assuming that  you have data in Range `A2:A4`.*

1. Apply **Text to column** Command on Data Range to split Numbers.

[image]

2. Write this formula in Cell `D2` & fill down.

   ```
      =SUMPRODUCT(--(LEN(TRIM(A2:C2))=7))
   ```

*Adjust cell references in the Formula as needed.*

Answer (score 0):

It does not seem as if you have a number in mind to test for as you refer to seven digit numbers in the string in a pretty generic way, so the following would do nicely:

```
=COUNT(  IF(  LEN(  FILTERXML("<Group><Members>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","</Members><Members>")&"</Members></Group>","/Group/Members"))  =  7,  FILTERXML("<Group><Members>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","</Members><Members>")&"</Members></Group>","/Group/Members"),  "")  )
```

The `FILTERXML()` portion uses standard JOINing to create an HTML string with two levels of tag:  `Group` which is the upper level, or container for all the members of the group (which are the individual numbers in the string), and `Members` which is the lower level, so to speak. In between the starting string and the ending string is a `SUBSTITUTE()`  that changes the " , " characters for Member level tags... but closing tag, then opening tag, which seems unnatural, but the opening string being JOINed has an opening tag, so the first one "in the middle" has to be the closer, and then a new opening tag, and so on until the ending JOINed string has the closers for it all. The second parameter is the `XPATH` that tells the function how to examine and break things up.

That all goes into an internal array that Excel passes on to the `LEN()` function which sits inside an `IF()` test checking for ones that have a length of seven digits. Any that do, it keeps the number and any that do not become `""`'s.

At this point you have zero or more seven digit numbers and zero or more `""` items. The `""` items are considered text by Excel, so `COUNT()` will ignore them, counting only the seven digit numbers that were in the string.

From the way you write about them, it does seem as if only one seven digit number will be present, though it may be there 10 times. In that case, the answer here is the answer you need. If you might have several different seven digit numbers in the strings, and need to check for one particular one, you will need some more work on the formula. That would take place in the `IF()` test:  just add an `AND()` to hold the existing length test and put in a test for whether the number found equals either a hardcoded value, or better, a cell address where you can enter different values if you care to.

(The `FILTERXML()` approach is currently the best way for splitting cells into word-like pieces.)